# Qt: У меня вопрос по поводу QStackedWidget И Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt

Используя Qt Designer я добавил в окно QStackedWidget и две страницы. Как я должен сделать так чтобы добавить в эти страницы кнопки и прочие виджеты? (Просто я только начал использовать этот Дизайнер). Если вам не полностью понятно то что я хочу сказать, я могу дополнить текст деталями.

Comment: Мне кажется, что там всё интуитивно понятно, изменяешь размер `QStackedWidget` на нужный, изначально в нём 2 странички, закидываешь туда нужные элементы, это первая, потом ПКМ по стакеду и жмёшь "следующая страничка", закидываешь на следующую, потом можно добавить страничек через контекстное меню, либо удалить там же.

Comment: Я имею ввиду как потом ими манипулировать? Как потом при нажатии кнопки менять виджет?

Comment: Менять CurrentIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу минимальный пример:

```
class Foo : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Foo(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent),
  stw_(new QStackedWidget(this))
  {
    QVBoxLayout* lo = new QVBoxLayout();
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(this);
    lo->addWidget(stw_);
    lo->addWidget(btn);
    this->setLayout(lo);

    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotChangePage()));

    addPages();
  }

private slots:
  void slotChangePage()
  {
    int index = stw_->currentIndex() + 1;
    if (index >= stw_->count()) {
      index = 0;
    }
    stw_->setCurrentIndex(index);
  }

private:
  void addPages()
  {
    // Здесь разместить код вставки страниц в QStackedWidget,
    // например, используя QStackedWidget::addWidget(QWidget*)
  }

private:
  QStackedWidget* stw_;
};
```